# How do I use Md5 in Indy?

Tags: delphi, md5, indy

I need to calculate MD5. Everywhere I search they tell me to use Indy, so ok I have:

```
hasher := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
```

Now I need to call a function numerous times updating the MD5 as I read the stream. How can I do this in Indy? I only see methods like HashStream that hash the entire stream.

Also after I calculate my hash I need to convert it to hex. I see there used to be be the function AsHex in Indy but it is not there anymore. 
So how do I convert result from a function like HashStream to hex string?

Comment: Use the BinToHex function for instance. But only if you need a text hash.

Comment: MD5 doesn't need Indy. You don't need to take a dependency if you'd rather not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIdHashMessageDigest...` (and `TIdHashSHA...`) does not have `public` live streaming hash methods at this time (`TIdHashCRC...`, `TIdHashAdler32`, and `TIdHashElf` do).  However, `TIdHashMessageDigest...` does have `protected` live streaming methods, so you can use an accessor class to reach them, eg:

```
type
  TIdMessageDigest5Access = class(TIdMessageDigest5)
  end:

var
  hasher: TIdMessageDigest5:
  ctx: TIdHashIntCtx;
  hash: TIdBytes;
  hex: string;
begin
  hasher := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  ctx := TIdMessageDigest5Access(hasher).InitHash;
  ...
  // call this as many times as needed...
  TIdMessageDigest5Access(hasher).UpdateHash(ctx, bytes);
  ...
  hash := TIdMessageDigest5Access(hasher).FinalHash(ctx);
  hex := TIdMessageDigest5Access(hasher).HashToHex(hash);
  ...
  hasher.Free;
end;
```

There are also various public `Hash...AsHex()` methods, such as `HashStreamAsHex()`.